# Is there a proper way to add NTLM auth type into SwiftMailer using SwiftMailer bundle in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, ntlm

I have symfony project with swiftMailer bundle. I was trying to send email via swiftmailer using NTLM auth. But I have not found a way to turn on NTLM via configuration of the bundle.

After struggling with it I have found solution

**First solution**

```
current($this->get('mailer')->getTransport()->getExtensionHandlers())
    ->setAuthenticators([new \Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_NTLMAuthenticator()]);
```

Comment spool in config.yml

```
#    spool:     { type: memory }
```

But it's look a little bit weird.

**Second solution**

Remove SwiftMailer bundle and use swiftMailer directly, because ntlm auth type activated by default.

Is there a better way to use NTLM auth type?

Comment: Your current solution/hack takes 1 line of code... As long as NTLM will not be supported by the swift mailer bundle, I doubt you could find a better solution...

Comment: @Kadriles, I mean via events or/and config. With working spool.

Comment: symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#auth-mode - Valid values are plain, login, cram-md5, or null. computer says no for the moment directly from the config.
I did find in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/preferences.php. Could you make your declaration in this file? I know it's in the vendor file and probably be overwritten on update but, if you want cleaner code, worth a shot and then leaving a note

Comment: According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502058/how-to-correctly-configure-symfony2-swiftmailer-bundle-to-work-with-smtp-server?rq=1 you can use smtp transport and default auth_mode.

Answer (score 3):

I created [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/pull/188) which got approved.

Since version `v3.0.4` you can use

```
  auth_mode: ntlm
```

You can install `v3.0.4` version using command

```
composer require symfony/swiftmailer-bundle:^3.0.4
```

Comment: Super. . . . . .